# Rust: Mutable borrow returns non-mutable borrow

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

Apologies if this is asked somewhere else before, but I'm not sure how to search for an answer to this one.

I have a piece of simplified code that demonstrates an issue I'm having in a larger piece of software. Basically I have what (to me) appears to be 2 immutable borrows of an item, however Rust appears to think that one of the borrows is mutable.

```
struct SomeStruct {
    val: i32
}

fn bor_mut(bor: &mut SomeStruct, new_val: i32) -> &i32 {
    bor.val = new_val;
    &bor.val
}

fn bor_nmut(bor: &SomeStruct) -> &i32 {
    &bor.val
}

fn main() {
    // get two non-mutable borrows,
    // but one originates from a mutable
    // borrow
    let mut s = SomeStruct{val: 1};
    let a = bor_mut(&mut s, 2);
    let b = bor_nmut(&s);
    println!("a = {}, b = {}", a, b);
}
```

Compiling this code gives the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `s` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:20:22
   |
19 |     let a = bor_mut(&mut s, 2);
   |                     ------ mutable borrow occurs here
20 |     let b = bor_nmut(&s);
   |                      ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
21 |     println!("a = {}, b = {}", a, b);
   |                                - mutable borrow later used here
```

which is simply the "mutable borrow with another borrow" error code. However, the only borrow that exists at line 20 is `a`, which is immutable. I see where Rust is coming from, since the borrow originates from an immutable borrow, but I don't see how that's relevant when the borrow itself is immutable?

The only reason I can think that this is intended is to prevent multi-threaded code from breaking the borrow checker, but I can't seem to think of a scenario in which this helps even there. However, if that's not the case, it does seem like an oversight in the way the borrow checker works.

I'm hoping someone is able to explain to me why the borrow checker works this way? Somehow this is the first time I've encountered this issue.

Comment: Yep, that's a perfect answer, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider this simple example:

```rust
// We've a buffer with 4 numbers
let mut original_v = vec![0, 1, 2, 3];
// Let's open a scope like if this were the body of a funcion called on `original_v`
{
    let exclusive_borrow = &mut original_v;
    // Let's take a shared reference to the last element
    let shared_borrow_to_first_elem = &v[3];
    
    exclusive_borrow.pop(); // Deletes last element (pointed by the shared reference)
    let v2 = *v1; // This now access invalid memory
}
```

If the code above were viable it would be easy to create dangling pointers, just allowing 1 exclusive reference (&mut) or multriple shared ones (&) this issue dissapears. I hope it has helped you to understand this concept.

I know that in your example you are not commiting any of this but it would be hard for the compiler to check if there are or if there are not dangling pointers that deep, so it just creates a fancy rule that prevents the problem.